# How to open a picture as a binary file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've been using sublime text 2 for some "programming" puzzle and it has to do with editing pictures and now I've switched to sublime 3 for plugin reasons and when I press "open with sublime" it opens the picture as a picture instead of binary file or in utf8. Now I get it that they wan't to add more features but this is a bit silly as I need sublime to be a text editor.

My problem is that I cannot find an option to open/reopen the file in sublime in bin/hex without changing the extension of the file.

How do I do that?